# Supply line never finished creating?

Tags: fallout-4

So, I tried to set up 2 supply lines, 1 from sanctuary to starlight and 1 from sanctuary to oberland, but neither of them have created. Theres no lines on my map telling me that the supply lines exist, but it wont let me send another settler to create a line. Am I missing a step, or is this a bug?

Comment: Quick way to check; if you have lots of resources in sanctuary, and none in the others (i.e. copper) check your available resource in the others (i.e. I should have no copper in this town, yet I can build a radio tower)

Comment: It takes time for the settler to travel to the destination, or perhaps they've been attacked. Did you equip the settler with some armour, weapons and ammo?

Comment: @DavidYell does it? Whenever I sent settlers on a supply run, I found all resources were available instantly, unless it was a bug in my game

Comment: @nickson104 Perhaps it's just a visual thing, but I can actually see my settlers with their brahmin travelling to the place and back.

Comment: @DavidYell they visually move with brahmin but the items are available immediately when you set up the supply line.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "wont let me send another settler to create a line"? What exactly did you try, and what exactly was the result? Companions can't be sent on supply routes for instance, so if you asked one of them that wouldn't work.

Comment: Did you just look at the normal map, or did you press the button to activate supply line view on the map? Also, did you check right after placing the supply line? If you waited a while, it's possible that the provisioners got killed by raiders. This will usually only happen if you are nearby the provisioner while raiders are there.

Answer (score 2):

If you approached the settlers in workshop mode, pressed the "supply line" command and selected a settlement you didn't miss a step.

The assigned settler should immediatly get a fresh brahmin for all the stuff and make his way to the assigned settlement. 
Also, when looking at the map in your pip-boy, press "C" on the keyboard (or L1/LB on PS4/XBOX). This will show you all the established supply lines, so you can verify that you haven't clicked the wrong settlement by accident.

Comment: Certainly. Looks fine now.

Comment: @Texenox: Ok, very good. Thanks to you both. I always have the tendency to answer problems as short as possible ^^

Comment: The current answer is perfect. As a side note: short answers automatically get flagged as low effort, so please avoid doing that.

Comment: @ardaozkal: ok, I'll keep that in mind. Thx for the help.